# TextView Position : how can it be a float value ? - Android

Tags: java, android, textview

I would like to know how it is possible to move a TextView with float values ? We cannot divide a pixel so how is it possible to write something like

```
TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
t.setX(1.5f);
t.setY(1.5f);
```

?
I just don't understand why we can put a float value here.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preferred geometric unit of measure in Android is dp (Density-independant pixels). The amount of pixels in a dp depends on the screen size of the device used. Using dp instead of actual pixels makes it easier to develop device independant apps.

Therefore, there is not really a reason why you can't have floating point dp!

However, `View.setX()` is used to set pixels (px), not dp. The only reason I can think of that this takes a floating value is to make convertion between dp and px easier.

However, they are not consistent in this. For example, the method `View.setBottom()` does take an `int` instead of a `float`.

Comment: EDIT : it is not in dp but in pixels : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setX%28float%29

"Sets the visual x position of this view, in pixels." ... I still don't understand...